# How to spool in Oracle properly

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sqlplus

I've created a spool command to export data from the Oracle into the csv. file. Here it is:

```
    set echo off
    set verify off
    set feedback off
    set heading on
    set termout on
    set pages 50000
    set newpage none
    spool Y:\Marketing\Nick\OptivoList\test.csv
    Select EMAIL || ',' || ',' || GENDER
    from Email_test;
    spool off;
    exit;
```

It creates output like that:

```
EMAIL,GENDER
-----------------
test1@test.com, M
test2@test.com, W
test3@test.com, M
```

The question- how to get rid that '----------' output between the headers and the   data?

Comment: I have updated my answer, now you could do it in just one step. `SET UNDERLINE OFF`. Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways -

1. **set underline off**

For example,

```
SQL> set underline off
SQL> select empno, ename from emp;

     EMPNO,ENAME
      7369,SMITH
      7499,ALLEN
      7521,WARD
      7566,JONES
      7654,MARTIN
      7698,BLAKE
      7782,CLARK
      7788,SCOTT
      7839,KING
      7844,TURNER
      7876,ADAMS
      7900,JAMES
      7902,FORD
      7934,MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

2. **Custom Column headers with pagesize 0**

You need to set **pagesize** to zero. This will suppress the **column headers** and repeating column headers. And then, apply your **custom column name** using an **UNION ALL** statement.

For example,

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> SELECT 'EMPNO' ||' , '|| 'ENAME' FROM DUAL
  2   UNION ALL
  3   SELECT EMPNO||' , '||ENAME FROM EMP
  4   /
EMPNO , ENAME
7369 , SMITH
7499 , ALLEN
7521 , WARD
7566 , JONES
7654 , MARTIN
7698 , BLAKE
7782 , CLARK
7788 , SCOTT
7839 , KING
7844 , TURNER
7876 , ADAMS
7900 , JAMES
7902 , FORD
7934 , MILLER

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```